# How can I download data saved to the Xbox Live cloud onto my Computer?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, xbox-network

A few years ago, I saved some game data in the Xbox Live cloud via Xbox 360. I would like to know how do I get that data without having the console. Is there any way to do this from the computer?

I'd like to get my Minecraft maps from Xbox 360 to convert to computer.